# Is there anyway to add multiple Tweet buttons on the same page and have their own Tweet Counts

Tags: twitter

I was thinking of setting up some tweet buttons for people to tweet out various sections of a long article using #anchor tags

eg a URL like this

```
http://www.w3schools.com/html_links.htm#tips
http://www.w3schools.com/html_links.htm#questions
```

There would be a Tweet button next to each Anchor Tag

Is this possible and will each tweet button have their own unique Count on their respective buttons?

eg

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://www.w3schools.com/html_links.htm#tips" data-text="I have Tweeted the Tips Link" data-count="horizontal">Tweet</a><script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>

<a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://www.w3schools.com/html_links.htm#questions" data-text="I have Tweeted the Questions Link" data-count="horizontal">Tweet</a><script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
```

Many thanks in advance

Cheers
Andy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twitter disregards #fragments in their tweet button counts so multiple tweet buttons linking to multiple sections of a single page will all have the same count. You can have multiple tweet buttons on a single page with different counts but they will have to be fore separate pages. For example a blog of `example.com` could have two tweet buttons with different counts but they would have to be for:

```
example.com/1
example.com/2
```

Comment: Thanks Abraham, that's what I thought. Shame there is not way to trick it or workaround.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to play with GET values. You can use this kind of url for the tweeter button :

```
http://www.w3schools.com/html_links.htm?anchor=tips
http://www.w3schools.com/html_links.htm?anchor=questions
```

Then, you add some JS to jump to the anchor when the user come from tweeter.